# Windows Azure uthentification via curl

Tags: azure, curl

In our enterprise, we use Azure AD for the authentification.

I want now to do some [curl](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html) commands for testing, but the command:

> curl -u myuser:mypassword https://www.thewebsite.com -L

doesn't do the trick. Apparently, I'm stuck at the login windows.

Has anyone else a solution to do the Azure authentification from curl?

***EDIT: as suggested by @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, adding `--ntlm` didn't work***

Comment: Have you tried this command curl --ntlm --user username:password http://example.com

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT I'm still stuck on the windows Login page

Comment: It is ntlm not ntml hope you used wrong command or is it a typo mistake in question

Comment: Yeah sorry, just a typo error ;)